# Google Play adds unwanted permission in my app

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I made APK through `gradlew assembleRelease`. My APK require next permissions:

```
> aapt d permissions app-release.apk
package: <my-package>
permission: <my-package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
uses-permission: name='<my-package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' maxSdkVersion='18'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
```

But when I'm uploading that apk to Google Play, I'm getting this permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
<my-package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

So, when I'm trying to update my app through Google Play, it requires additional permission (previous version didn't require android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). But if I'm opening same apk on the device itself, it doesn't require permission.

Maybe, I really need this permission, but my apk doesn't contain it (and should crash at runtime). So, why Google add it and how i can avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has already been answered in the below question:

[Google Play shows the implicit READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976822/google-play-shows-the-implicit-read-external-storage-permission)